# Using ifelse statement in R dataframe to generate additional variables

Tags: r, if-statement, nested, conditional-statements

I've got a dataframe in R with the following possible combinations in the first two columns:

```
 V1| V2| V3| V4
---|---|---|---
 0 | 0 | NA| NA
---|---|---|---
 0 | 1 | NA| NA
---|---|---|---
 0 | 2 | NA| NA
---|---|---|---
 1 | 0 | NA| NA
---|---|---|---
 1 | 1 | NA| NA
---|---|---|---
 1 | 2 | NA| NA
---|---|---|---
 2 | 0 | NA| NA
---|---|---|---
 2 | 1 | NA| NA
---|---|---|---
 2 | 2 | NA| NA
```

I would like to generate two ifelse statements or one if possible, so that I can get these two additional columns based on the different combinations:

```
 V1| V2| V3| V4
---|---|---|---
 0 | 0 | 0 | AA
---|---|---|---
 0 | 1 | 1 | AD
---|---|---|---
 0 | 2 | 2 | DD
---|---|---|---
 1 | 0 | 0 | AB
---|---|---|---
 1 | 1 | NA| NA
---|---|---|---
 1 | 2 | 1 | CD
---|---|---|---
 2 | 0 | 0 | BB
---|---|---|---
 2 | 1 | 0 | BC
---|---|---|---
 2 | 2 | 0 | CC
```

I'm really stuck at this point and none of the options I have tried work.

If I try something like this:

`DF$V3 <- if((DF$V1=2) & (DF$V2 = 2)) {DF$V3 = 0}`

All values in V1 and V2 are converted into 2 and all values in V3 are converted to 0.

If I use the elseif command in the following way:

`DF$V3 <- elseif((DF$V1=2) & (DF$V2 = 2)) {DF$V3 = 0}`

I get Error: could not find function "elseif"

I have read several forums about nested if and elseif statements in R, but I'm not able to figure out how to get the results I want using two conditions on two different columns.

Can somebody suggest any options?

Thank you very much,

Best,

Yatrosin

Comment: It's `if (conditional) { true-block-1 } else if { true-block-2 } else { false-block }`. There is no function `elseif`, ergo your error message. Are you thinking about `ifelse`? It's a vector-centric conditional.

Comment: `else if` isn't a stand alone function in R (it can be used with a full if statement). Use `ifelse(test, yes, no)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Up front**: I think the use of `ifelse` statements in this problem is strongly ill-advised. It requires significant nesting, sacrificing performance and readability. Though these two solutions may be a little harder if you aren't familiar with `mapply` or table-join-calculus, the payoff in stability and performance will far outweigh the time to learn these techniques.

Two methods:

### Lookup matrix

One way is to define look-up arrays, where the row ***names*** reflect the possible `V1` values, and the column names reflect the possible `V2` values. (Note that when referencing these lookup matrices, one must use `as.character` if your values are numeric/integer, since otherwise they will look for the slice/row number, not the specific matching column/row.)

Examples:

```
dat <- data.frame(
  V1 = c(0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2),
  V2 = c(0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2)
)
dmnms <- list(c(0,1,2), c(0,1,2))
m3 <- matrix(c(0, 1, 2,
               0, NA, 1,
               0, 0, 0),
             nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE, dimnames = dmnms)
m4 <- matrix(c("AA", "AD", "DD",
               "AB", NA, "CD",
               "BB", "BC", "CC"),
             nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE, dimnames = dmnms)

m3
#   0  1 2
# 0 0  1 2
# 1 0 NA 1
# 2 0  0 0
m4
#   0    1    2   
# 0 "AA" "AD" "DD"
# 1 "AB" NA   "CD"
# 2 "BB" "BC" "CC"
```

in this case, notice the `0`, `1`, and `2` in the row/column margins. In a matrix with no names, these are typically `[1,]`, `[2,]`, etc, indicating that actual names are not available, instead reflecting just the row number. However, since these are `character` (no brackets/commas), they can be referenced directly, ala

```
m3["0","2"]
# [1] 2
m4["1","0"]
# [1] "AB"
```

From here, you just need to map these lookups into new columns, something like:

```
dat$V3 <- mapply(`[`, list(m3), as.character(dat$V1), as.character(dat$V2))
dat$V4 <- mapply(`[`, list(m4), as.character(dat$V1), as.character(dat$V2))
dat
#   V1 V2 V3   V4
# 1  0  0  0   AA
# 2  0  1  1   AD
# 3  0  2  2   DD
# 4  1  0  0   AB
# 5  1  1 NA <NA>
# 6  1  2  1   CD
# 7  2  0  0   BB
# 8  2  1  0   BC
# 9  2  2  0   CC
```

### Joining data.frame

Another method is to *join* a known `data.frame` onto your data. This has an added benefit of easily expanding to more than two criteria. (Technically, the `matrix` method can expand to more than 2, in which case it would be an `n`-dim `array`, but it is often a little harder to edit, manage, and visualize.)

In your example, this doesn't initially gain you much, since you need to pre-define your data.frame, but I'm guessing that this is just representative data, and your conditional classification is on much more data.

I'll define the joiner `data.frame` that will be used against your actual data. This is the reference data, from which all input permutations will be defined into the respective `V3` and `V4` values.

```
joiner <- data.frame(
  V1 = c(0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2),
  V2 = c(0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2),
  V3 = c(0, 1, 2, 0, NA, 1, 0, 0, 0),
  V4 = c("AA", "AD", "DD", "AB", NA, "CD", "BB", "BC", "CC"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

I'll create a sample second data to demonstrate the merge:

```
dat2 <- data.frame(
  V1 = c(2, 0, 1, 0),
  V2 = c(0, 1, 2, 2)
)
merge(dat2, joiner, by = c("V1", "V2"))
#   V1 V2 V3 V4
# 1  0  1  1 AD
# 2  0  2  2 DD
# 3  1  2  1 CD
# 4  2  0  0 BB
```

**Edit**: if you are concerned about dropping rows, then add `all.x=TRUE` to the `merge` command. If (as you saw based on your comment) you use `all=TRUE`, this is a *full join* in SQL parlance, meaning it will keep all rows from both tables, even if there is not a match made. This may be better explained by referencing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20298671/3358272) and noting that I'm suggesting a *left join* with `all.x`, keeping all on the left (first argument), only merging in rows on the right where a match is made.

(Note: this can also be done quite easily using `dplyr` and `data.table` packages.)

Comment: The first option works in the example I described here. When I tried to apply this method to my actual data I get this error though: Error in .Primitive("[")(dots[[1L]][[1L]], dots[[2L]][[28L]], dots[[3L]][[28L]]) : 
  subscript out of bounds

Comment: That's because you either (a) did not correctly define the row and column names of the lookup matrices, or (b) did not use `as.character`, instead trying to index `m3` or `m4` using numeric/integer indices. I cautioned against this. In my example, `dmnms` (short for dim-names) and therefore `m3` and `m4` *must* include all possible combinations of `V1` and `V2`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I would have never manage to write this code

Comment: There is something weird with the way I'm applying the merge function. Whenever I apply this method I get two additional observations than the original ones (647 vs 645). When I use Damian's code this does not happen and I get the actual 645 original observations with the additional columns. `merge(DF, joiner, by = c("V1", "V2"), all= TRUE)` . I just added the "all=TRUE" to avoid missing the rows with NA values.

Comment: Okay, good point ... try `merge(..., all.x = TRUE, all.y = FALSE)`. Take a look at the "SQL database terminology" paragraph of [`?merge`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/merge.html), with some help on [SQL join types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20298671/3358272). If that doesn't work, [meet me on chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149533/temp-help).

Comment: For the crowd, one remaining issue was resolved in chat: since `merge` changes the order of rows, it might be useful to *first* add a column to indicate the row number, perhaps `dat$row <- 1:nrow(dat)`, and then post-merge, reorder with `dat <- dat[dat$row,]`.

Answer (score 2):

Building on the first half of the post by @r2evans, using named vectors to do multidimensional lookups instead of matrices. The logic is the same, but I find the syntax to be easier to interpret/debug.

```
dat <- data.frame(
    V1 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
    V2 = c(0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2)
) 

# Use a named vector to store key-value pairs:
#   keys: combinations of V1 and V2 in text form
#   values: the desired result associated with each combination

V3_lookup <- c("0,0" = 0,
               "0,1" = 1,
               "0,2" = 2,
               "1,0" = 0,
               "1,1" = NA,
               "1,2" = 1,
               "2,0" = 0,
               "2,1" = 0,
               "2,2" = 0)

V4_lookup <- c("0,0" = "AA",
               "0,1" = "AD",
               "0,2" = "DD",
               "1,0" = "AB",
               "1,1" =  NA,
               "1,2" = "CD",
               "2,0" = "BB",
               "2,1" = "BC",
               "2,2" = "CC")

# Create a character vector with the inputs 
# (the combinations of V1 and V2 that actually occur in the data)

id <- paste(dat$V1, dat$V2, sep = ",")
id
[1] "0,0" "0,1" "0,2" "1,0" "1,1" "1,2" "2,0" "2,1" "2,2"


# Map these strings to the desired outputs

dat$V3 <- V3_lookup[ id ]
dat$V4 <- V4_lookup[ id ]

# Result
dat

  V1 V2 V3   V4
1  0  0  0   AA
2  0  1  1   AD
3  0  2  2   DD
4  1  0  0   AB
5  1  1 NA <NA>
6  1  2  1   CD
7  2  0  0   BB
8  2  1  0   BC
9  2  2  0   CC
```

Comment: Not bad, not bad ... though in my experience, the client (or data) will then show `V1` or `V2` values with commas in them, providing unreliable lookups. Contrived, certainly, but shows a hint of fragility of this otherwise elegant and easy-to-read solution.

Comment: I agree this is much easier to read. Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 1):

In your example you have a suite of potential outputs:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(V1 = rep(0:2, each=3), V2 = rep(0:2, 3))

df %>% 
   mutate(V3 = ifelse(V1==0 & V2==1 | V1==1 & V2==2, 1, 
                  ifelse(V1==0 & V2==2, 2, 
                         ifelse(V1==1 & V2==1, NA,0))),
      V4 = ifelse(V1==0 & V2==0, 'AA',
                  ifelse(V1==0 & V2==1, 'AD',
                         ifelse(V1==0 & V2==2, 'DD',
                                ifelse(V1==1 & V2==0, 'AB',
                                       ifelse(is.na(V3), 'NA',
                                              ifelse(V1==1 & V2==2, 'CD',
                                                     ifelse(V1==2 & V2==0, 'BD',
                                                            ifelse(V1==2 & V2==1, 'BC','CC')))))))))
```

Without a more complete understanding of your data this is about the best I can come up with.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `ifelse()` statement with multiple conditions:

```
ifelse(a == 1 & b == 2, TRUE, FALSE)
```

In R you need to use `==` to check for equality.

For example:

```
df <- data.frame(
+ x = c(1,1,2,2),
+ y = c(3,3,4,4))


df$z <- ifelse(df$x==1 & df$y==3, "Yes","No")

df
  x y    z
1 1 3  Yes
2 1 3  Yes
3 2 4   No
4 2 4   No
```

Comment: I have tried with something similar before: `ifelse(DF$V1=2 & DF$V2 = 2, DF$V3 = 0, DF$V3 = -9)` and I always get the error: Error: unexpected '=' in "ifelse(DF$V1="

Comment: @Yatrosin Note my other comment: "In R you need to use `==` to check for equality."

Comment: Also, don't specify `DF$V3` in the `ifelse` statement. Instead `DF$V3 <- ifelse(test, 0, -9)`